# React - prop undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning to build apps with React (not using Redux yet). So far everything is working as expected except when it comes to load the data (via ajax). Let me refine what I mean.

I'm using the spotify API using the library "spotify-web-api-js".

So far, I have 2 components:

1. Search Field
2. Display the list of Artists

Of course everything is wired up on the App level.

1. App Level

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      artists: []
    }

    this.searchArtists('Chris');
  }

  searchArtists(artist) {
    api.searchArtists(artist, (err, data) => {
      if (err) { console.log(err); };
      this.setState({ artists: data }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.artists);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const artistSearch = (artist) => { this.searchArtists(artist); };

    return (
      <div>
        <Search onSearchTermChange={ artistSearch } />
        <SearchResult artists={ this.state.artists.artists } />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

2. Search

```js
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { artist: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar">
        <input
          value={ this.state.artist }
          onChange={ event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value) }
          placeholder="Search by Artist" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onInputChange(artist) {
    this.setState({ artist });
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(artist);
  }
}

export default Search;
```

3. Search Results

```js
const SearchResult = props => {
  if (!props) {
    console.log('loading');
  }

  return <li></li>;
}
```

THE PROBLEM

I'm trying to display the results in SearchResult, but it always returns undefined. I tried a settimeout but I know that's the not the solution to my problem.

Why would `props` return undefined? Even if the data seems to return fine.

I will continue digging for a simple answer and will Edit the question if I find something.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So here is the response I get in the console:

```js
{
  artists: {
    artists: {
      href: 'sikshdksad',
      items: [array],
      limit: 20,
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

There are 2 artists, because `this.state = { artists: [] }` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write `artists` twice when passing down the prop? `this.state.artists.artists`

Comment: @Tholle yup that's my problem. I should remove the array initialization in order to remove that second "artists"

Comment: What does the `data` from the API look like? Have you tried just setting `artists` to `data.artists` when the request is done instead of just `data`?

Comment: Yes I did, instead of `console.log(this.state.artists)`, I can access it via `console.log(data)`. I can add it to my answer - how the data looks like if you want.

Comment: are you sure data has an object called `artists`?

Comment: I'll show the json response here. Sorry got busy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're initially defining your artists state as an array:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    artists: []
  }

  this.searchArtists('Chris');
}
```

You eventually set that to whatever `data` returns in your return function. But when you reference the artists data to pass in as a prop, it looks like you're trying to access the `artists` value *on* the `artists` object:

```
<SearchResult artists={ this.state.artists.artists } />
```

Maybe just get rid of that last `.artists`?

Comment: Yup this I'm aware, will remove the array initialization. But does it explain why the data is returning undefined? I mean, we can still access the information.

Comment: because the data you have is at `this.state.artists`. but it's probably not true that the object at `this.state.artists` also has an `artists` property. Try turning `this.state.artists.artists` => `this.state.artists`